# getting an odd division error with PHP number_format()

Tags: php, math, number-formatting

my script calculates a number X by dividing two other numbers, A by B.

X=A/B

when i use number_format(A,2) on A before calculating X, i get a very odd number. Actual figures:

1,045.00 / 5 = 0.2

but if i don't use number_format on A before the division, i get the correct answer. Is number_format somehow making A into a non-number?

1045 / 5 = 209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_format` should be used only while pretty printing the number. Its return value should not used in calculation as you did.

Example:

If `$A = 1045;`
then `number_format($A,2)` will be `1,045.00` now if you treat `1,045.00` as a number it will be `1` as comma and remaining char will be ignored and `1/2` is `0.5` which you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`round(A, 2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), not `number_format()` which is for string representations (hence named "format").

Answer (score 1):

The docs show that number_format returns a string. Have you tried casting the result of number_format() to a numeric type before your mathematical manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. It could be better if we use number format dec_point and thousand_separator parameters. you could use number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); It will help to remove your thousand separator

Answer (score 0):

[`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) makes it into a string with commas between thousands, and the comma will be confusing the divisor into thinking that's the decimels based on your locale.